# dual boot not working with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, windows-10

I installed ubuntu 16.04.2 as a dual boot with windows 10, the installation was successful but now I am not able to access ubuntu!
I tried all the answers I found here and in other websites, but still not working!
I don't have any idea what to do, or where to search for new solutions to try!
pretty new to this :))

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you get an error? Did you configure your BIOS the right way? Pls specify your question!

Comment: @Mofty I tried to do it as recovery option but it didn't recognise the USB as a recovery device in the first place, then I tried to do through ubuntu system's terminal, to update the grub list, then I tried through windows command prompt with this command :" bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi", but still didn't work.

Comment: Do you see the grup list on start? Did you deactivate fast boot in windows? I don't even know yet what your real problem is... The problem, that you can't boot your installed Ubuntu aside.

Comment: when I try to deactivate the fast startup from Power option, it does not give me this option at all!, and my problem is that when I restart or turn on mu laptop I don't get to see any grub list to choose which kind of boot I want to work on windows or ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

(live-USB solution worked for me and required no technical knowledge.)